# Numerical Recipe is a header only library

Tags: numerical-recipes

Is Numerical Recipe is a header only library ?

I have only the header files. I am not sure do I need to buy the license ?

Answer (score 0):

For C++, the answer is yes. This library is not free. You can buy the dvd that has the source files from [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521880688). In Windows, basically you need to include the path to the library. I usually do

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I D:\CPP_Libraries\NR\code
```